# Prevent cycling / wrapping to first buffer after last

Tags: buffers

I have opened multiple buffers and I cycle between them using `:bnext` and `:bprevious`. How can I prevent vim from cycling to the first buffer when using `:bnext` on the last buffer / cycling to the last buffer when using `:bprevious` on the first buffer?

Basically, I want the same behavior as when opening vim with multiple files in the argument list and cycling between those using `:next` and `:Next`/`:previous`. In that case, vim will show `E165: Cannot go beyond last file` when using `:next` on the last file and `E164: Cannot go before first file` when using `:Next` on the first file.

If that is not possible, I could make do with vim displaying a message when cycling to the first / last file, similar to the message displayed when wrapping around a search: `search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP`.

Comment: Put the relevant buffers in the arglist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst there isn't a vim-native option to configure this, you can simulate it by writing your own functions to overload `:bnext` and `:bprev`.

```
function! Bnext()
    let bufnrs = range(1, bufnr("$"))
    call filter(bufnrs, {_, v -> buflisted(v)})
    if bufnr() == max(bufnrs)
        echo "You are at the last buffer"
    else
        bnext
    endif
endfunction

command! Bnext call Bnext()

function! Bprev()
    let bufnrs = range(1, bufnr("$"))
    call filter(bufnrs, {_, v -> buflisted(v)})
    if bufnr() == min(bufnrs)
        echo "You are at the first buffer"
    else
        bprevious
    endif
endfunction

command! Bprev call Bprev()
```

I have assumed that you want to filter out unlisted buffers.  If you decide to go this route, some ideas for extending it are:

- use `-bang` to enable/disable going to the next unlisted buffer
- use `-count` to go to the nth next/previous buffer in the list
- use `:cnoreabbrev` to use `:Bnext` when you type `:bn` (see [here](https://gist.github.com/romainl/56f0c28ef953ffc157f36cc495947ab3#enlightenment) for an example)